# How to send photos to a specific channel when used with a prefix?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want a photo to go to a specific channel when I add it's prefix to it. The photo moves to the channel without using a prefix. I want it to ONLY send when I use a prefix in the post with the photo.

```
const prefix = '***';

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if ((!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) && (message.attachments.size > 0)) {
        const docsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "docs")
        docsChannel.send({files:[message.attachments.first().url]});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [negation (`!`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) from your `if`. Your current code is:

```js
if ((!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) && (message.attachments.size > 0)) {
```

Which effectively means: 
"send the picture to the channel if the prefix is **not** '**' and there is an image".

change it to:

```js
if ((message.content.startsWith(prefix)) && (message.attachments.size > 0)) {
```